# WF4: "instance owner registration for owner ID has become invalid' errors

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

We have an windows workflow application hosted in WCF and IIS. We have turned on tracing in this application and we are seeing a large number of

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceOwnerException: The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance owner registration for owner ID has become invalid. This error indicates that the in-memory copy of all instances locked by this owner have become stale and should be discarded, along with the InstanceHandles. Typically, this error is best handled by restarting the host.
```

or

`System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceNotReadyException: No runnable workflow instances were found` errors.

The windows workflow endpoint is exposed via a WCFWorkflowService.xamlx file which has a designer file but does not have a code behind file. In this case, how would I check if "the instance handle is still valid before calling the instance store" i.e implement the solution documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639055/wf4-instancepersistencecommand-interrupted)?

The SqlWorkflowInstanceStore is not exposed in my code, it is configured in my web.config file.

**"windows workflow application hosted in WCF and IIS" configuration:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug include ExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <sqlworkflowInstanceStore connectionString="Data Source=
                    <DatabaseConnectionString>" instanceEncodingoption="Gzip" instanceCompletionAction="DeleteNothing" instanceLockedExceptionAction="BasicRetry" hostLockRenewalperiod="68::30"
    runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="80:00:05"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**client configuration:**

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://www.URLInProduction.com/WCFWorkflowService.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService contract="WCFServiceReference.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
```

Comment: Before using instance storage, always check whether the handle is still valid.You can refer to this link, the problem in the link is the same as the one you encountered, I hope it helps you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639055/wf4-instancepersistencecommand-interrupted

Comment: Thank you @Dingpeng, I had checked the link that you have send, However the part that I do not understand is how to change the application to implement the documented solution? The application does not implement IWorkflowInstanceStore, the application is configured in the web.config.

Comment: I did not see the information about the endpoint in your configuration file, it may be caused by this reason.

Comment: The workaround that I have come up is to change the application to use the windows workflow application as a "project reference" instead of a 'service reference". Once that's done then we can change the application to create an instance of IWorkflowInstanceStore as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639055/wf4-instancepersistencecommand-interrupted